# Why can't I find a plug for inside a breaker box

Tags: electrical-panel, receptacle

I'm doing some work with power tools at a location nearish to the breaker box, but pretty far from any outlets. I'm guessing I haven't found a fused breaker-box outlet because they aren't made because ... failure of the plug could result in sparks in the fuse-box which could kill power to the house (and this being electrician work) starting a fire burning everything down. Is that correct, or are my suspicions wrong and there is a part and I just can't find it?

Comment: Why do you want to open the breaker box to do work nearby? It's easy to mount an outlet just outside the breaker box. Why in it?

Comment: Seems a lot of work to have an outlet/receptacle inside of the breaker box.  Every time you want to plug something in, you need to open the door and unscrew the face plate, then unplug, screw the face plate on again and close the door when you are finished.

Comment: @jay613 The breaker box is outside the house per recent codes ostensibly to allow access for the FD in the event of fire. I won't have work in this location long term, and I would remove the outlet after this work was done - I suspect that would be cheaper than mounting an outlet outside and then removing it.

Comment: @crip659 You're basically right. Once this job is done, I won't have work in this location and I would remove the outlet.

Comment: If it's temporary a long extension cord is probably the cheapest, easiest solution and it'll come in handy in future.

Answer (score 4):

North America answer.

In an oversized equipment or control cabinet, if work is performed within the cabinet often enough to make this worthwhile, you can assemble an outlet in a junction box within it and there are [DIN-rail mounted devices](https://www.wago.com/us/cpo)  to make this easier.

In a residential breaker panel:

- there is not enough room to do this, and not enough need to make it practical or to justify a product for this purpose.  It's normal to install an outlet right next to the panel, connected by an offset nipple, for convenience in working near or within it.  (Although, I need to imagine if you are working with *corded* power tools inside a breaker panel you surely have the main breaker off?  I mean, what are you doing? I'm just not sure I understand the question.)
- anything that requires power and must reside inside the panel (the only thing that comes to mind is energy monitors) will be designed to be powered without a plug and socket.

Answer (score 2):

If your breaker panel uses a DIN rail system (common in Europe) then you can easily find outlet that will fit on there.

In the american-style busbar design the convenience outlet is usually put in next to or below the panel. Using a short bit of conduit to allow an electrician to visually inspect the entire circuit before they use it.

Comment: lazyness? Though DIN rails are used in applications that isn't a residential breaker box. In those applications having a outlet can be handy/necessary. And a previous owner of my house did exactly that, the washer and dryer were next to the panel and they put in 2 outlets in the panel to power them. They redid the electricity and put in proper surface mount outlets for them and didn't dispose of the old panel and the stuff in it.

Comment: Sorry I meant my previous comment for the question not here.  In North America the equivalent of a DIN-rail mounted outlet would be a couple of wire nuts.  Anything designed to be powered inside the breaker panel would not have a plug, it would just have a pair of wires powered from a breaker, either directly or via nutted tails.   Energy monitors are an example.